# Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\phpmailer\src\SMTP.php:306)

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

знаю, что тема избитая, но 3 дня на форумах не помогли справиться конкретно с этим случаем. В php новичок.
Делаю форму для сайта, которая отправляет введённые данные на почту заказчика, валидатор js и phpmailer.
Форма отправляется на почту, но нет сообщения для пользователя об успешной отправке и форма не очищается.
Понимаю, что ошибка скорее всего из-за файла SMTP, но не знаю, можно ли его как-то грамотно изменить, либо перенести мой заголовок перед ним, чтобы не сломать и всё продолжало работать.

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\phpmailer\src\SMTP.php:306) in C:\sendmail.php on line #

Что уже было испробовано:

1. Оба файла, которые вылетают в ошибке (SMTP и мой php) не имеют пробелов в начале
2. Имеют кодировку UTF-8 без BOM
3. В php.ini output_buffering = On
4. Изменение в output_buffering = 4096 на 14096 тоже не помогло
5. ob_start(); и ob_end_flush(); но возможно не туда вставляю

Файлы phpmailer на всякий случай:
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/src/SMTP.php

```
код script.js
"use strict"

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  const form = document.getElementById('form');
  form.addEventListener('submit', formSend);

  async function formSend(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let error = formValidate(form);

        let formData = new FormData(form);

        if (error === 0) {
            let response = await fetch('sendmail.php', {
                method: 'POST', 
                body: formData
            });
            if (response.ok){
                let result = await response.json();
                alert(result.message);
                // alert("Данные отправлены! С Вами свяжутся в ближайшее время");
                form.reset();
            } else {
                alert("Что-то пошло не так, попробуйте, пожалуйста, ещё раз");
            }
        } else {
            alert('Пожалуйста, заполните обязательные поля');
        }
    }
    function formValidate(form) {
    let error = 0;
    let formReq = document.querySelectorAll('._req');

    for (let index = 0; index < formReq.length; index++) {
      const input = formReq[index];
            formRemoveError(input);

            if (input.getAttribute("type") === "checkbox" && input.checked === false) {
                formAddError(input);
                error++;
            } else {
                if (input.value === '') {
                    formAddError(input);
                    error++;
                }
            }
        }
        return error;
    }
    function formAddError(input) {
    input.parentElement.classList.add('_error');
    input.classList.add('_error');
  }
  function formRemoveError(input) {
    input.parentElement.classList.remove('_error');
    input.classList.remove('_error');
  }
});

код sendmail.php
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

require_once 'phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require_once 'phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require_once 'phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->setLanguage('ru', 'phpmailer/language/');
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;

$mail->Host = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->Username = 'example@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'secret';

//from
$mail->setFrom('example@gmail.com', 'Do You Speak?');
//to
$mail->addAddress('mymail@gmail.com');
$mail->IsHTML(true);
//theme
$mail->Subject = "[Заявка с формы]";

$body = '<h1>Привет! Это письмо пришло, потому что кто-то оставил заявку на сайте.</h1>';

if (trim(!empty($_POST['name']))){
    $body.='<p><strong>Имя:</strong> '.$_POST['name'].'</p>';
}
if (trim(!empty($_POST['number']))){
    $body.='<p><strong>Телефон:</strong> '.$_POST['number'].'</p>';
}
if (trim(!empty($_POST['email']))){
    $body.='<p><strong>E-mail:</strong> '.$_POST['email'].'</p>';
}

$mail->Body = $body;

if(!$mail->send()) {
    $message = 'Ошибка';
} else {
    $message = 'Данные отправлены! С Вами свяжутся в ближайшее время :)';
}

$response = ['message'=> $message];

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
//ошибки
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
?>
```

Comment: Если вы **сами** включили отладочный вывод в phpmailer, то почему удивляетесь, что он что-то выводит?

Comment: А в чем фишка писать ini_set('display_errors', '1'); *в самом низу кода?* Типа чтобы сообщения об ошибках не мешали программисту? :)